# WPF - How can I get newly inserted row data row grid

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

By default my grid is empty, I am trying to get the row data that user insert to my grid , somehow after commit change, I have to idea how to get ,  I try use grid.SelectedItem , but the it always return null ,

My XAML code as below

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="grdInfo" Height="373" VerticalAlignment="Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0" RowEditEnding="grdInfoSave" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="No" Binding="{Binding No}" Width="50" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Binding="{Binding Total}" Width="120" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

My Cs Code for committing edit is as below

```
 private void grdInfoSave(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e )
 {
      if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
      {
        //Try to get the user inserted value and process it
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)grdInfo.SelectedItem;
        int No = Convert.ToInt32(row["No"]);
      }
 }
```

Code for generate table

```
 private void genTable()
 {
        DataTable dtInfo = new DataTable(); 

        dtInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("No", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
        dtInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", Type.GetType("System.String")));
        dtInfo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Total", Type.GetType("System.String")));

        grdInfo.ItemsSource = dtInfo.DefaultView;  
 }
```

What I need is when user enter 1 for `No` column , Apple for Description , 200 for total , I wish to get the entire row data.

Comment: Where would user enter the data at?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan At the GUI , I allow the property CanUserAddRow , which mean user can add row on their own

Comment: No no, I meant, would it be dynamic? and also, don't you have any class to populate the data for?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan i have posted the way I generate my table

Answer (score 1):

You can access newly inserted row to datagrid using following.

```
private void grdInfoSave(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e )
 {
      if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
      {
        //Try to get the user inserted value and process it
        DataRow newrow= e.Row.DataContext as DataRow; // If datarow does not work, replace will required databind class.
        String new_desc = newrow["Description"].ToString();
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)grdQuoteDetail.SelectedItem;
        int No = Convert.ToInt32(row["No"]);
      }
 }
```

Source - http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2009/09/29/Inserting-Updating-and-Deleting-from-a-WPF-DataGrid.aspx

Comment: e.Row.DataContext always return null